# What's the difference between 'verbose_name' and 'name' fields in a constructor of the Model class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

#### What's the difference between 'verbose_name' and 'name' fields in a constructor of the Model class?

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name of Account", "Name", max_length=64)
```

I found that "Name of Account" is `verbose_field` and "Name" is `name`.
I know `verbose_field` is used for a field name in Admin page.
But I don't know where the `name` field is used for?

```py
createdAt = models.DateTimeField("Created At", auto_now_add=True)
```

And why does the `name` not used in this field?

Answer (score 3):

Name will be use as a field name, for example:

If you have:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    some_text = models.CharField(name="bla", max_length=64)
```

When you use this model you can see that you have a property `bla` but not have a property `some_text`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 
Is `verbose_name` just a name to display in the admin page. and 
Is `name` a real field name in database. 
Is it correct?